# Fortran compilation output into specific location

Tags: compilation, fortran

I have a module file in the include directory, which I compile using Makefile from root directory.

`$(FC) -c include/my_mod.F90`

Compilation works fine, just my module shows up in the root directory instead of the include directory. How can I specify location of the output file?

I am using linux system, and I would like to support both gfortran and ifort.

Comment: This will depend on your compiler, so please give further detail. And it's the `.mod` file not the `.o` (again, change the extensions to suit your system) you want to control?  For gfortran, for example, you can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8855896/3157076).

Comment: Maybe use an option to specify where to put the `.mod` files (when I'm not mistaken: gfortran `-J`, Intel `-module`).

Comment: `$(FC) -c include/my_mod.F90 -module include/ -o include/my_mod.o` works perfectly! Thanks. I assume I have to write support for gfortran/ifortran (to switch `-J` and `-module`) by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank @albert and @francescalus, the solution is:

```
ifeq ($(FC),ifort)
        FORTFLAGS=-module
else
        FORTFLAGS=-J
endif

module:
        $(FC) -c include/my_mod.F90 $(FORTFLAGS) include/ -o include/my_mod.o
```